# Understanding Pass-By-Value-Result

Tags: pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Consider the following program

```
int i;
int a[2];
void foo(int x, int y)
{
    x++;
    i++;
    y++;
}

main()
{
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 1;
    i = 0;
    foo(a[i], a[i]);
    print(a[0]);
    print(a[1]);
}
```

I'm trying very hard to understand pass-by-value-result. However couldn't get the hang of it. I know it's similar to pass-by-reference. But in what way? How does the results differ in the above case? When does it actually use the "reference" of the values?

Comment: "I know it's similar to pass-by-reference." What do you mean by _similar_?

Comment: Aren't they similar except when aliasing occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results are:

> 2
>
> 1

This is because, in pass-by-value-result, any modification done to the variables within the calling function, will not be updated until the function exits.

With the same program, using pass-by-reference,

> 3
>
> 1

would be printed, because it references to the same address and updates any modification done immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in your posted code, you wanted "foo(a[i], a[i]);" instead of "p(a[i], a[i]);".

Anyway, your a[0] and a[1] will stay set at 1, because foo() gets arguments by value, and there is no way for foo() to change its arguments in a manner visible to the outside.

Passing by value and passing by reference are similar only because both execute a "passing". Passing by value involves a duplication of the data: foo() receives a copy of a[0] and a copy of a[1]; and foo() calls them x and y. Then foo() increments both, but x and y are copies only visible to foo(), so nothing happens in reality because x and y are no more used after the increment.

Inside foo() there is an increment of the variable i, which is global. This time instead, the variable gets really modified, and the change is visible to everybody.

Passing by reference is different in the sense that foo() would receive an address (the reference) of a variable, and foo() would be able to read but also write "in" that reference, thus modifying the object living there.

Think about this example. I am the main() and you are the foo(). I have a sheet of paper with something written in it, say the title of a song. I can let you know the name of the song by taking another sheet, copying onto it the name, and giving the new sheet to you. This is passing by value.

Different would be if I said to you: "the sheet is on the table" (the table is the location of the data, the "reference"). You go there, look at the sheet, so you know the title of the song. But you could also modify my sheet that lies on the table. This is passing by reference: I tell you *where* the data is. Of course, to be precise, the way I say to you where the sheet is, is accomplished by taking another sheet and writing on it "the sheet with the title is on the table", then I give you the new sheet. You, foo(), receive a sheet (passed by value), and you can also destroy or modify it, I will never notice. But before modifying this new sheet which will be useless soon or later, use it to look on the table and don't modify MY sheet with the name of the song on it! :-)

Comment: I understand pass-by-value and pass-by-reference, but what about pass-by-value-result? Isn't that a different thing?

Comment: @NewbieCoder In this case I don't understand the question. In the posted code there are no "results"; it seems that the code should show what happens when parameters are passed by reference, but they are not.

Comment: Well, my question is actually about `pass-by-value-result`. What would be printed in the code instead?

Comment: @NewbieCoder     "a[0] = 1; a[1] = 1;"; then nothing modifies them, so "1, 1" will be printed out. Assuming this code is plain C as it seems. This is because they are passed by value (C language doesn't have "pass by reference").

Comment: What about `pass-by-value-result`? Not `pass-by-value`. I do understand that any modifications done will not be affected when it comes to `pass-by-value` but what's for `pass-by-value-result`?

Comment: @NewbieCoder sorry, I don't have anything else to add. Your code example can not, in any way, be related to pass-by-value-result. Or, if it can, it only shows that in C you can not have that pass-by-value-result. Other languages used to have it, perhaps fortran.